# npm won't change version

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to change npm versions from 6.4.1 to 8.12.0 and it refuses to change. I'm running Windows x64. I've tried uninstalling, rebooting, deleting the AppData\Roaming\npm related files, installing the new version from nodejs.org, and running npm install again. I've tried where.exe npm to find more files. I've tried specifying the version number in npm install. Nothing works.

`npm -v` still returns `6.4.1`.

Interestingly,

`npm view npm versions --json`

returns this:

> [
>     "1.1.25",
>     "1.1.70",
>     "1.1.71",
>     "1.2.19",
>     "1.2.20",
>     "1.2.21",
>     "1.2.22",
>     "1.2.23",
>     "1.2.24",
>     "1.2.25",
>     "1.2.27",
>     "1.2.28",
>     "1.2.30",
>     "1.2.31",
>     "1.2.32",
>     "1.2.8000",
>     "1.3.0",
>     "1.3.1",
>     "1.3.2",
>     "1.3.4",
>     "1.3.5",
>     "1.3.6",
>     "1.3.7",
>     "1.3.8",
>     "1.3.9",
>     "1.3.10",
>     "1.3.11",
>     "1.3.12",
>     "1.3.13",
>     "1.3.14",
>     "1.3.15",
>     "1.3.16",
>     "1.3.17",
>     "1.3.18",
>     "1.3.20",
>     "1.3.21",
>     "1.3.22",
>     "1.3.23",
>     "1.3.24",
>     "1.3.25",
>     "1.3.26",
>     "1.4.0",
>     "1.4.1",
>     "1.4.2",
>     "1.4.3",
>     "1.4.4",
>     "1.4.5",
>     "1.4.6",
>     "1.4.7",
>     "1.4.8",
>     "1.4.9",
>     "1.4.10",
>     "1.4.11",
>     "1.4.12",
>     "1.4.13",
>     "1.4.14",
>     "1.4.15",
>     "1.4.16",
>     "1.4.17",
>     "1.4.18",
>     "1.4.19",
>     "1.4.20",
>     "1.4.21",
>     "1.4.22",
>     "1.4.23",
>     "1.4.24",
>     "1.4.25",
>     "1.4.26",
>     "1.4.27",
>     "1.4.28",
>     "1.4.29",
>     "1.5.0-alpha-0",
>     "1.5.0-alpha-1",
>     "1.5.0-alpha-2",
>     "1.5.0-alpha-3",
>     "1.5.0-alpha-4",
>     "2.0.0-alpha.6",
>     "2.0.0-alpha.6.0",
>     "2.0.0-alpha.7",
>     "2.0.0-alpha-5",
>     "2.0.0-beta.0",
>     "2.0.0-beta.1",
>     "2.0.0-beta.2",
>     "2.0.0-beta.3",
>     "2.0.0",
>     "2.0.1",
>     "2.0.2",
>     "2.1.0",
>     "2.1.1",
>     "2.1.2",
>     "2.1.3",
>     "2.1.4",
>     "2.1.5",
>     "2.1.6",
>     "2.1.7",
>     "2.1.8",
>     "2.1.9",
>     "2.1.10",
>     "2.1.11",
>     "2.1.12",
>     "2.1.13",
>     "2.1.14",
>     "2.1.15",
>     "2.1.16",
>     "2.1.17",
>     "2.1.18",
>     "2.2.0",
>     "2.3.0",
>     "2.4.0",
>     "2.4.1",
>     "2.5.0",
>     "2.5.1",
>     "2.6.0",
>     "2.6.1",
>     "2.7.0",
>     "2.7.1",
>     "2.7.2",
>     "2.7.3",
>     "2.7.4",
>     "2.7.5",
>     "2.7.6",
>     "2.8.0",
>     "2.8.1",
>     "2.8.2",
>     "2.8.3",
>     "2.8.4",
>     "2.9.0",
>     "2.9.1",
>     "2.10.0",
>     "2.10.1",
>     "2.11.0",
>     "2.11.1",
>     "2.11.2",
>     "2.11.3",
>     "2.12.0",
>     "2.12.1",
>     "2.13.0",
>     "2.13.1",
>     "2.13.2",
>     "2.13.3",
>     "2.13.4",
>     "2.13.5",
>     "2.14.0",
>     "2.14.1",
>     "2.14.2",
>     "2.14.3",
>     "2.14.4",
>     "2.14.5",
>     "2.14.6",
>     "2.14.7",
>     "2.14.8",
>     "2.14.9",
>     "2.14.10",
>     "2.14.11",
>     "2.14.12",
>     "2.14.13",
>     "2.14.14",
>     "2.14.15",
>     "2.14.16",
>     "2.14.17",
>     "2.14.18",
>     "2.14.19",
>     "2.14.20",
>     "2.14.21",
>     "2.14.22",
>     "2.15.0",
>     "2.15.1",
>     "2.15.2",
>     "2.15.3",
>     "2.15.4",
>     "2.15.5",
>     "2.15.6",
>     "2.15.7",
>     "2.15.8",
>     "2.15.9",
>     "2.15.10",
>     "2.15.11",
>     "2.15.12",
>     "3.0.0",
>     "3.1.0",
>     "3.1.1",
>     "3.1.2",
>     "3.1.3",
>     "3.2.0",
>     "3.2.1",
>     "3.2.2",
>     "3.3.0",
>     "3.3.1",
>     "3.3.2",
>     "3.3.3",
>     "3.3.4",
>     "3.3.5",
>     "3.3.6",
>     "3.3.7",
>     "3.3.8",
>     "3.3.9",
>     "3.3.10",
>     "3.3.11",
>     "3.3.12",
>     "3.4.0",
>     "3.4.1",
>     "3.5.0",
>     "3.5.1",
>     "3.5.2",
>     "3.5.3",
>     "3.5.4",
>     "3.6.0",
>     "3.7.0",
>     "3.7.1",
>     "3.7.2",
>     "3.7.3",
>     "3.7.4",
>     "3.7.5",
>     "3.8.0",
>     "3.8.1",
>     "3.8.2",
>     "3.8.3",
>     "3.8.4",
>     "3.8.5",
>     "3.8.6",
>     "3.8.7",
>     "3.8.8",
>     "3.8.9",
>     "3.9.0",
>     "3.9.1",
>     "3.9.2",
>     "3.9.3",
>     "3.9.4",
>     "3.9.5",
>     "3.9.6",
>     "3.10.0",
>     "3.10.1",
>     "3.10.2",
>     "3.10.3",
>     "3.10.4",
>     "3.10.5",
>     "3.10.6",
>     "3.10.7",
>     "3.10.8",
>     "3.10.9",
>     "3.10.10",
>     "4.0.0",
>     "4.0.1",
>     "4.0.2",
>     "4.0.3",
>     "4.0.5",
>     "4.1.0",
>     "4.1.1",
>     "4.1.2",
>     "4.2.0",
>     "4.3.0",
>     "4.4.0",
>     "4.4.1",
>     "4.4.2",
>     "4.4.3",
>     "4.4.4",
>     "4.5.0",
>     "4.6.0",
>     "4.6.1",
>     "5.0.0",
>     "5.0.1",
>     "5.0.2",
>     "5.0.3",
>     "5.0.4",
>     "5.1.0",
>     "5.2.0",
>     "5.3.0",
>     "5.4.0",
>     "5.4.1",
>     "5.4.2",
>     "5.5.0",
>     "5.5.1",
>     "5.6.0",
>     "5.7.0",
>     "5.7.1",
>     "5.8.0-next.0",
>     "5.8.0",
>     "5.9.0-next.0",
>     "5.10.0-next.0",
>     "5.10.0-next.1",
>     "5.10.0",
>     "6.0.0-next.0",
>     "6.0.0-next.1",
>     "6.0.0-next.2",
>     "6.0.0",
>     "6.0.1-next.0",
>     "6.0.1",
>     "6.1.0-next.0",
>     "6.1.0",
>     "6.2.0-next.0",
>     "6.2.0-next.1",
>     "6.2.0",
>     "6.3.0-next.0",
>     "6.3.0",
>     "6.4.0-next.0",
>     "6.4.0",
>     "6.4.1-next.0",
>     "6.4.1"
>   ]

Please help!

Comment: The post title is about `nodejs` You can check it's version with `node -v`. But in the post you mention `npm` which is the package manager of nodejs. Which one do you want to update?

Comment: npm...changing the title now

Comment: As of now, [6.4.1 is the latest version of npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm) . There is no version 8.12.0. Might you be confusing node with npm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably confusing node's version with NPM.

The latest version of NPM as of now is 6.4.1, and of NodeJS is 11.2.0, so you are already at the latest version. 8.12.0 doesn't exist yet.

Check here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm

https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: *facepalm* yep, that was it

Comment: Happens, don't stress about it :)